# Custom GraphQl $args is empty on Interface custom attribute resolver

Tags: graphql

Here is my schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
    products (
        special_code: String @doc(description: "special code")
    ): Products
}

interface ProductInterface {
    addl_data: String @doc(description: "additonal data") @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\AddlData")
}
```

On my resolver file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class YourPrice implements ResolverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }

        $this->_logger->debug("args: " . var_dump($args));
        $this->_logger->debug("special_code: " . $args['special_code']);
        return 'something test';
    }
}
```

However, $args is empty

```
[2022-03-29 09:38:56] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:56] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:56] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:57] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:57] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:57] main.DEBUG: args:  [] []
[2022-03-29 09:38:57] main.ERROR: Notice: Undefined index: special_code in
```

How do I access my custom input argument and access it from my output custom field resolver?

Comment: Same issue I am facing for products query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @rainebow did you found any solution for this, I am facing same issue

Comment: same problem.. any solution?

Comment: @RanjitShinde Added answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Interface custom attribute resolver code
2. Check your code for any errors or missing code. Ensure that your resolver class implements the Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface interface and that you have correctly defined the resolve method.
3. Check the Interface custom attribute type code
   Ensure that you have properly defined the custom attribute type in your schema.xml file and that it is linked to the appropriate resolver. Also, check that the arguments are properly defined for the field in the schema file.